# jQuery: can the empty() method be given a duration?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, can the empty() method be given a duration, such that the object fades to empty over a period of time (for example, 500 milliseconds)?

Here is the current code:

```
$('#object_to_be_emptied').empty();
```

Comment: Also consider `.hide()`, which animates the element's opacity and the width/height.  Only animating the opacity will cause a jump when the animation ends and the elements are removed.  (Everything below the removed elements will move up.)

Answer (score 21):

No. Fade the content out, then empty it when the fade is complete.

```
$('#object_to_be_emptied').children().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#object_to_be_emptied').empty();
});
```

---

This code unfortunately calls `empty` as many times as there are elements under `#object_to_be_emptied`.  If you are using jQuery > 1.6, you can get round this with the `$.Deferred` support for animations:

```
$('#object_to_be_emptied').children().fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
    $('#object_to_be_emptied').empty();
});
```

Comment: Instead of fading out each of the child elements, why not [just fade out the containing element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269710/jquery-can-the-empty-method-be-given-a-duration/6269877#6269877)?  This way, your callback will be called exactly one time.

Comment: @josh Because then the element itself will be hidden. I presume from the question that this is not desired behaviour.

Comment: If it's being emptied, there's nothing to display anyway, assuming the container is a vanilla `<div>`.  You are right, however, if the container has styling like a fixed size and borders.  In this case, the styling should be applied to a wrapper around the container, so that we can safely apply the animation to only the container.

Comment: @josh It might be that content will be immediately added to the element.

Comment: True - if that were the case, I'd `fadeOut`, `empty`, populate, and then `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 5):

The other two answers suggest using `$('#object_to_be_emptied').children().fadeOut()`, but it is actually a bad idea to use `.children()` because this will cause an animation to be applied to *each* of the child elements within your containing element (killing performance), and therefore execute the animation complete callback once for each element within `object_to_be_emptied`.  With more than just a couple of elements, this will turn into a real problem.

Instead, just apply the animation to the containing element, remembering to call `.fadeIn()` after you've repopulated it and want to show it again.

```
$('#object_to_be_emptied').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).empty();
});
```

Also note that I've used `this` in the callback function – jQuery sets `this` to be the DOM element which is the target of the callback function; in this case, `object_to_be_emptied`.  Using `this` saves some typing and makes code changes down the line easier.

Answer (score 1):

you're probably looking for something like:

```
$('#object_to_be_emptied').children().fadeOut(500,function(){
  $('#object_to_be_emptied').empty()
});
```